# How can i use Svg picture asset as leading property in List tile flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, svg

How can i use Svg picture asset as leading property in List tile flutter?
The code blew gives me an error:

```
ListTile(
      leading: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          color: Colors.purple
        ),
          child: SvgPictures.assset(Images.svgBulb)),
      title: Text('Management',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,color: Colors.black),),
      subtitle: Text('2 Courses',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,color: Colors.grey),),
    )
```

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: Undefined name 'SvgPictures'...then i tried  Image(image: SvgPictures.asset('svgFlame')),its still not displaying svg image

Answer (score 0):

You use the wrong name, change this:

```
child: SvgPictures.assset(Images.svgBulb)),
```

to :

```
child: SvgPicture.asset(Images.svgBulb)),
```

Comment: @Adi did my answer help you or you were looking for something else?